# Display all items in TableView from a List of objects that have a List as a data field (JavaFX, TableView, FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, observable

Couldn't think of a good title, but bear with me...

**Person class:**

```
public class Person {
private int pid;
private List<Insurance> insurances;
}
```

**Insurance class**

```
public class Insurance {
private int amount;
}
```

And then I have an `ObservableList<Person> persons` which I use to display all persons in a TableView (excluding the Insurance-List). I want to display ALL insurances in a different TableView, dynamically adding and deleting. 
I have tried this, but it does not work dynamically when I delete and add to the personsData list of objects.

```
ObservableList<Insurance> insurances = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (Person person : personsData) {
        insurances.addAll(person.getInsurances());
    }
```

It works fine when I add and delete persons to the personsData-List, but when I add and delete from the List within the personsData-List, it does not work dynamically.

Hope this is understandable.

I use FXML, JavaFX, TableView, TableColumn, Property-fields etc. for the GUI. This example is very simplified as my project is quite large.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am guessing that when you delete a row from one `TableView`, that you can delete the row of the other `TableView`.

Comment: The person.insurances isn't observable and therefore isn't firing any table or change listener logic.   Is the insurance table a unique list across all people or complete list with duplicates? What's the goal or the insurances table? Adding other insurances to a person?

Comment: @kendavidson the goal is to register customers, and register insurances connected to existing customers. Also editing and deleting existing customers/insurances.How can I make person.insurances observable? The insurances table is supposed to show all registered insurances, from all customers. If you know about a tutorial or other answered questions here I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Getting the tutorial is an easy thing, getting it so that it matches what you're trying to do is the right thing.  I'm still curious about the TableView<Insurance> that shows a non unique list of Insurances across all people.  I don't understand what it's for? There is no reference back to a person, so it's not helping you there.  It's got duplicates, and could possibly be missing some Insurance that isn't applied to anyone.  I could see it being used as showing ONLY the insurances for the selected Person, which is a completely different thing.